# Aurelia SystemJS out of stack space

Tags: javascript, aurelia, jspm

I have been using Aurelia for a while with JSPM and everything has been fine until today.  I loaded my project and get the error (SystemJS) Out of stack space.  The project loads perfectly in Edge, Firefox, Chrome, and SAfari but just with IE it has this error and won't load my project.

Has anyone encountered this issue?  How did they solve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried it before on IE?

Comment: Yes, and it worked fine.  I just recently did an upgrade to Aurelia and that's when it went to pot.

Comment: running out of stack space often means loop-recursion. Does console log tell you anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of issues in the past when updating my JSPM version. The only way I've found to resolve them is to reinstall all your jspm packages by deleting your config.js file and reissuing the jspm install [list of packages]